# (2.79) How do I make a plane transparent without making the texture transparent?

Tags: transparency

I want to make the plane with the texture transparent, but I don't want the texture to be transparent. to be clear, the texture is a png file with some parts being transparent, but I cannot figure out how to make the plane transparent without making the texture transparent.
I'm using Blender version 2.79.

Answer (score 0):

so actually I'm an idiot and forgot to use face textures and alpha face textures
I got it working
whoops